# how to add int and int[ ] in java using var args method?

Tags: java

This is my first question so I might sound stupid, so please don't mind !
I was working on a concept which is var args and I come up with a program as follows :

```
package Method;
public class VariableArguments {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    m1();
    m1(10);
    m1(10,20);
    m1(10,20,30,40);
    m1(10,20,30,40,50);
}
public static void m1(int... x)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i:x)
    {
        total = total + x;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: "+total);
 }
}
```

While I was running this program, I was getting an error which is-

> Error:(15, 27) java: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
>
> first type:  int   second type: int[]

In line 15 it says "Operator '+' cannot be applied on int, int[]"

So can anybody give me the solution for this problem ?
Thanks !!

Comment: Should be `total = total + i;` You're iterating over `x` array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `total` to `i` (each element), not to the var args. array (i.e., `x`), so change the code as:

```
total = total + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to do math operations with totally incompatible data types... you are in fact trying to add an integer with an array of ints

you mean for sure

```
total = total + i;
```

since both are the same type(int)

by doing this

```
total = total + x;
```

you are adding int to an array of ints...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid silly mistakes , you need to learn the **for-each** method :

```
for(int i : x) // this means for every integer value *i* in array *x*
{
      total = total + i ;// this line add the i to total , 
     //total = total + x ;//here array is bad operand for '+' operator .
}
```

change your code by the above snnipet , or you can also use simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this :

```
total = total + x;
```

`x` is the array. You can't use the `+` operator on arrays, and therefore the error. **Since you are iterating over the array** `x`,I sense you wanted this:

```
total = total + i;
```